# How to implement Bash to make it possible to execute "cat | ls" command?

Tags: c, linux, shell

I have been trying to develop a mini shell program in C which acts like a Bash mostly. However, I have a problem about executing this command: `cat | ls`. In my program, when I execute this command it waits for an input from the `stdin` and it only prints the output of the `ls` command when `cat` reaches to the `EOF` which happens only when I send `ctrl+D` signal to the program. On the other hand, in Bash, when I execute `cat | ls` command, it first prints the output of `ls` command to the `stdout` and waits for an input from the `stdin` and stop executing the whole command after entering one line of input to the `stdin`.

I created a minimal, reproducible example of my program, and it works in the same way.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void execute_block(char **block)
{
    int pid;

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        if (execve(block[0], block, NULL) == -1)
        {
            perror(block[0]);
            exit(127);
        }
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
}

void handle_commands(char **block1, char **block2)
{
    int pid;
    int pipefd[2];

    if (pipe(pipefd) == -1)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        close(pipefd[0]);
        dup2(pipefd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(pipefd[1]);
        execute_block(block1);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    close(pipefd[1]);
    dup2(pipefd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
    close(pipefd[0]);
    waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
    execute_block(block2);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)
{
    char *block1[] = {"/bin/cat", NULL};
    char *block2[] = {"/bin/ls", NULL};

    handle_commands(block1, block2);
}
```

Why doesn't my program act in the same way as Bash does. Is it related to the way I handle pipes? or is it something else? Also could this problem occur due to the way I use waitpid() functions?

Comment: It looks like your `handle_commands()` function executes `block1` in both parent and child.  I presume that you intended one of those to execute `block2`, instead.

Comment: Yes, it should be block2 instead of block1. Thank you for that. However, thats not the problem. I made that mistake when I was posting that question to here. I will edit the question.

Comment: It also looks like you are `fork()`ing excessively. `single_or_more_command()` forks to execute `handle_commands()`.  Then `handle_commands()` forks to run the first block, and both forks fork *again* in `execute_block()`.  You should not need more than one child process per block (plus, perhaps, additional children for nested blocks).

Comment: This line from `execute_block()` looks suspicious: `dup2(data->original_stdout, STDOUT_FILENO);`.  It appears that that would sometimes counteract the pipe setup that was done in `handle_commands()`.

Comment: `ls` doesn't read from stdin, so why would it wait?

Comment: Yes, I fork excessively but there is a reason for that. Long story short, I use these excessive forks to prevent the program from being terminated. However, I also tried to delete those excessive forks but it didn't work. For this line: `dup2(data->original_stdout, STDOUT_FILENO);`. I have to use it to print the errors, which could be occur when calling `execv()`, to the `stdout`. But also, I deleted that line too. However, the problem still continues.

Comment: I know that the `ls` doesn't read form the `stdin` but it waits to read. I couldn't figure out why it is waiting?

Comment: Error messages should go to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  If they do, then redirections of `stdout` do not affect them.

Comment: If `ls`'s output is being delayed as you describe when executing `cat | ls`, then it's likely that `ls` is not running at all until after `cat` terminates.  I don't recognize what, if anything, in the code presented is causing that, but you ought to be able to confirm by using the `ps` command (in another terminal) while the `cat` is waiting for input.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre]. Instead of whole routines (but not a whole program), you should reduce the problem to **just** code that executes `cat` and `ls`. Give a whole program (with `main` and everything needed to compile and build) with just a little code. It does not even need to redirect streams unless the problem will not reproduce without it.

Comment: I edited the question and added a minimal, reproducible example of my program. Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: bash is a specific shell that's a huge superset of POSIX sh. If you want a very baseline shell, that's not implementing "bash".

Comment: Beyond that -- we have _hundreds_ of "why don't pipes work in my toy shell?" questions already in our knowledgebase, and they mostly end up with the same set of answers (there's a small number of common mistakes). Asking another copy of that very common question is not a good use of anyone's time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `handle commands` code is basically

1. fork a child
2. in the child

   - run the block1 command (in a grandchild, waiting for that grandchild before continuing)
   - exit
3. in the parent

   - wait for the child to exit
   - run the block2 command (in another child, waiting for that child before continuing)
   - exit

So this means the `ls` (the block2 command) won't run at all until the child (the `cat` in the block1 command) exits.

A normal shell (like bash) will fork another child and use that to run block2 *before* waiting -- the parent will wait (for both children) after both have been started, so they'll run concurrently.

The extra children you're running in `execute_block` don't help here, as the parent waits for them to complete before proceeding.